# Unity crashes every time I try to stop the movement of my object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, monodevelop, rigid-bodies

I'm making a non random generated runner game and I'm trying to code the boss entry and fight. So the game consist of an astronaut (player) that stays on screen all the time (so him, background and camera never move, well the player can move but it's clamped.

All the hazards come towards the player and he has to avoid them or defeat them until the last hazard which is the boss. The boss is at the end of the line and goes along the z-Axis as well towards the player and I want it to stop when it collides with a Quad, so the boss is static and they can fight.

After that I want the boss to move up and down and shoot the player with Lerp functions.

The code looks like this:

```
public class BossController : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
public float health;
public Animator anim;
public Transform startMarker;
public Transform endMarker;

private Rigidbody rb;
private HUDController hud;
private bool startIntro = false;

private float startTime;
private float journeyLength;

void Start () {
    startTime = Time.time;
    journeyLength = Vector3.Distance (startMarker.position, endMarker.position);

    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    rb.velocity = transform.forward * -speed;

}

void Update(){

    //transform.position += transform.forward * -speed * Time.deltaTime;


    if (startIntro) {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        Fight ();
    }
}

void Fight(){

    float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
    float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;

    while(true)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startMarker.position, endMarker.position, fracJourney);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(endMarker.position, startMarker.position, fracJourney);
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("bossEntry")) {
        startIntro = true;
        //anim.SetTrigger ("quad"); 
    }
}
```

}

I tried first with the rigidbody and when it collides, the rigidbody's velocity is 0 and that works fine AS LONG AS the Fight() method is commented. So maybe it's because of the lerp functions?

When it;s not commented when the boss hits the collider everything freezes and I cannot use Unity anymore and I have to restart the programm.

Please help!

Edit: I removed the while(true) loop and now the boss falls straight down when it collides with the quad instead of lerping. The Boss is under an empty object and both start and end markers are under the empty object as well. Every component is attached to the empty object (parent).

[image]
[image]

Comment: btw I haven't implemented the shooting yet

Comment: `while(true)` - well, that's an *endless* loop. You might want a way to get out of it.

Comment: yes, but I want the boss to lerp endlessly until it's defeated

Comment: Well, this way, the whole game is busy lerping, and nothing else can ever happen.

Comment: If you to to keep that while loop, convert it to coroutine and yield every frame.. Like what @Corak said, having a while(true) in a single frame will cause an infinite loop and may lead to an exception like StackOverflowException

Comment: ohhh okay I understand, so how can I make a lerp repeat?

Comment: Since you are calling `Fight()` inside the `Update()` method, you can remove `while(true)` inside `Fight()`

Comment: The `Update()` method will be called every frame, so `Fight()` will also be called every frame since it is inside `Update()`

Comment: should I still make it a coroutine if I delete the loop?

Comment: You can do either of the following, remove the `while(true)` if you are going to call it inside the `Update()` function OR move the `Fight()` call outside of `Update()` then convert it to coroutine. I suggest just remove the `while(true)` loop though

Comment: I removed the `while(true)` and now it does not crash anymore when it collides with the quad but instead of lerping it falls down

Comment: Make sure that the endMarker transform does not change your y value unless necessary, or check the Rigidbody properties.

Comment: how would it change it? I dont have any more code that affects the endMarker. I will add two images so you can see the hieararchy of the boss and the inspector with the components

Comment: @bonishadelnorte `I want the boss to lerp endlessly until it's defeated` That would mean you use `while(!bossIsDefeated)`, not `while(true)`.

Comment: thank you @Flater :) but that is already solved, now my object falls when it collides instead of lerping

Answer (score 0):

try and track (print) the values of your veriables. 
I'd guess you have a divisor of 0 here - 
float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;

if not, its most likely you have an endless loop, or a null pointer which is vital.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just noticed this now.

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startMarker.position, endMarker.position, fracJourney);
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(endMarker.position, startMarker.position, fracJourney);
```

The second Lerp overrides the value of first one immediately. If you want something like a ping pong effect, make a flag to determine the current state you want.

```
bool toEndMarker = true;
void Fight() {
    //Some code here
    if(toEndMarker)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startMarker.position, endMarker.position, fracJourney);
        if(//DETERMINE if transform.position is already at end marker)
        {
            toEndMarker = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(endMarker.position, startMarker.position, fracJourney);
        if(//DETERMINE if transform.position is already at start marker)
        {
            toEndMarker = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! but I already solved it, I attached 2 different scripts, one with the movement along the z-Axis and one with the lerping and when it collides the movement stops and the boss just lerps and it works :)